# Dreamweaver CS6 - How do I stop slider on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, onmouseover

Below is the jquery code.. I'm wondering how and where exactly in code do I have to enter function, when i go over slider it pause sliding.. And then when I move mouse out of slider, it continues to slide photos..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.photo').hover(function() {

        $(this)
            .find('.caption')
            .stop()
            .animate({
                bottom: '0'
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'easeOutQuart'
            });
    }, function() {

        $(this)
            .find('.caption')
            .stop()
            .animate({
                bottom: '-100px'
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'easeOutQuart'
            });

        var interval = setInterval(slideSwitch, 2000);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function as a shortcut:

```
$(function() {
    var interval = setInterval( slideSwitch, 10000 );

    $('#slideshow').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function() {
        interval = setInterval( slideSwitch, 10000 );
    });
});
```

Here is a link for a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7yCyR/).